# Consuming WCF methods - abort / closing

Tags: .net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I am consuming WCF in my ASP.NET MVC app and each of my methods contains try-catch-finally block. I am wondering if I am closing / aborting WCF call correctly.
I know that "using" statement is not good for WCF calls.

Here is the sample metod

```
public int GetInvalidOrdersCount()
{
    OrderServiceClient svc = new OrderServiceClient();
    try
    {
        return svc.GetInvalidOrdersCount();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        svc.Abort();
    throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        svc.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735103.aspx) it shows an example of the 'proper' way to call:

```
CalculatorClient wcfClient = new CalculatorClient();
try
{
    Console.WriteLine(wcfClient.Add(4, 6));
    wcfClient.Close();
}
catch (TimeoutException timeout)
{
    // Handle the timeout exception.
    wcfClient.Abort();
}
catch (CommunicationException commException)
{
    // Handle the communication exception.
    wcfClient.Abort();
}
```

I usually follow this pattern when implementing clients.  Except, you would probably also want to dispose with a `using` for the client:

```
using (CalculatorClient wcfClient = new CalculatorClient())
{
    try
    {
        return wcfClient.Add(4, 6);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException timeout)
    {
        // Handle the timeout exception.
        wcfClient.Abort();
    }
    catch (CommunicationException commException)
    {
        // Handle the communication exception.
        wcfClient.Abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: David, so how am I going to return something from the service? Declare a variable, get value, close the call and then return the variable?

Comment: @303 you can just return the result from inside the `try`.  Once you make the call, you will have the value.  The dispose won't affect the result.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like the `WcfUsingWrapper` below, and then wrap all my proxy instances

```
    void Foo(){

        var client = new WcfClientType();
        var result = ExecuteClient(client, x => x.WcfMethod());

      }

    public static ReturnType ExecuteClient<ReturnType>(ClientType client, Func<ClientType, ReturnType> webServiceMethodReference)
where ClientType : ICommunicationObject
    {
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            ReturnType result = webServiceMethodReference(client);
            client.Close();
            success = true;
            return result;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                client.Abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you'll want to do is check the "state" of the connection. If the channel is in a faulted state, you need to call the Abort() method before closing, otherwise the channel will remain faulted for some time. If the channel is not faulted, just calling Close() works fine. Then set it to null.

Something like this:

```
 if (requestChannel != null) {
    if (requestChannel.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Opened) {
        requestChannel.Close();
        requestChannel = null;
    }

    if (requestChannel.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Faulted) {
        requestChannel.Abort();
        requestChannel.Close();
        requestChannel = null;
    }
 }
```